# 16.04 LTS/Gnome 3 - Launcher will not hide and other issues

Tags: gnome, launcher, dell, gallium

I find that the Launcher in Ubuntu 16.04 (server) with Gnome 3.18.5 doesn't hide and the cursor is jumpy and unstable. This problem only started a few weeks ago and I honestly don't recall what the trigger was.

Installing Gnome 3.18.5 and upgrading from 16.04 to the latest didn't help.  Here's my config:

- 16.04, kernel 4.4.0-45
- Display card is Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (lvm3.8 256 bits)
- Dell T320 server, 64-bit, 16Gb RAM, 12 CPUs